# The bubblesort is not sorting all the elements

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have a small question regarding this bubblesort algorithm below. I ran in VS, but its not giving me the sorted output, its just switching the places of the 2nd and the last element of the array. Can someone please look into it and debug it please?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Arraysort {
    
    static void sort(int[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n-i); j++) {
                if (array[j-1] > array[i]) {
                    temp = array[j-1];
                    array[j-1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int array[] = {2,6,7,9,5};


        System.out.println("This is my unsorted Array\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }

        sort(array);

        System.out.println("This is my sorted Array\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:
2
5
7
9
6

Comment: array[j-1] > array[j]) instead of array[j-1] > array[i])

Comment: Have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: _"... Can someone please look into it and debug it please ..."_ - One of the most useful ways a novice programmer can spend their time is learning to use their debugger.  If you become a career programmer, it will save you literally _years_ of your life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is because you have used the j range 1 to n-i. the problem here is when you use 1 to (n-i) it will skip one checking cycle of the list. So what you need to do is run algorithm n times (j < n ) in order to make sure you go through the all cycles in the list.

change j < (n-i) to j < (n)

```
public class Arraysort {
    static void sort(int[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n); j++) {
                if (array[j - 1] > array[i]) {
                    temp = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array[] = { 2, 6, 7, 9, 5 };

        System.out.println("This is my unsorted Array\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }

        sort(array);

        System.out.println("This is my sorted Array\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```